# Adding a Link in Wygwam causes the link to break

Tags: wygwam

I have a Wygwam 3.2.1 field inside ExpressionEngine 2.5.3. When I add a link to a PDF like so using the Source editor;

```
<p>You can download the <a href="/media/downloads/document.pdf">guide</a> to find out more about .</p>
```

It renders like so in the view source on the front end;

```
<p>You can download the <a href="&lt;/p">
                                </a></p>
```

In the browser, this obviously just cuts the text off after '... download the '.

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "Restrict allowed HTML?" to 'No' in the Wygwam configuration settings. This is located on the WYGWAM Module settings page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anna. I don't seem to have that Restrict allowed HTML option. :/

Comment: Try uploading all the WYGWAM 3.2.1 files to your install again. Sounds like something isn't correct.

Comment: Hey Anna. For some reason this didn't fix the issue. :(